# Compile-Build KDSoap libraries

Tags: c++, qt, 32bit-64bit

my problem is build in 32 bits version, the library KDSoap but my system is 64 bits, (i do builded easily version of 64 bits).
In documentation says execute a python script and later execute a MAKE file(in the python options only use static and release), exist a file of g++.pri (here i modify the lines adding -m32 in CFLAGS),

Here is mi g++.pri

```
*-g++* {
NORMAL_CFLAGS = -Wno-long-long -ansi -m32 
win32-g++ {
NORMAL_CFLAGS += -U__STRICT_ANSI__
}


NORMAL_CXXFLAGS = \
 -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Wundef -Wcast-align \
 -Wchar-subscripts -Wpointer-arith \
 -Wwrite-strings -Wpacked -Wformat-security \
 -Wmissing-format-attribute -Woverloaded-virtual

# -Wconversion gives too many warnings from Qt-4.4.3 with gcc-4.3.2 (was fine with gcc-4.2.4), so removing it

NORMAL_CFLAGS += -pedantic -m32

CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
NORMAL_CXXFLAGS += -O0 -g3 -m32 
NORMAL_CXXFLAGS -= -g
}

USABLE_CXXFLAGS = -Wold-style-cast -m32 
HARD_CXXFLAGS = -Weffc++ -Wshadow -m32 
PITA_CXXFLAGS = -Wunreachable-code -m32 

QMAKE_CFLAGS   += $$NORMAL_CFLAGS 
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += $$NORMAL_CFLAGS $$NORMAL_CXXFLAGS 

kdab:QMAKE_CFLAGS_WARN_ON   += $$NORMAL_CFLAGS -Werror 
kdab:QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_ON += $$NORMAL_CFLAGS $$NORMAL_CXXFLAGS -Werror 

#QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_ON += $$USABLE_CXXFLAGS
#QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_ON += $$HARD_CXXFLAGS # headers must compile with this, code doesn't need to; needs patched Qt
#QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_ON += $$PITA_CXXFLAGS # header would be nice, but it's probably pointless, due to noise from Qt and libstdc++

}
```

I probed using a Qt version of 32 bits, but i get a lot errors( like says "libQt5... is incompatible"), when i use a qt version of 64 bits, i only get errors like that:
"/usr/bin/ld: se salta el /home/artur/proyects/KDSoap/lib/libxmlcommon.a incompatible find -lxmlcommon" (this error is repeated for every will generate file .so)

Comment: Messing with C/CXXFlags directly shouldn't be necessary if you use the right mkspec. Try `./autogen.py -spec linux-g++-32` after adding your 32 bit Qt's qmake to the PATH.

Comment: yes, thanks, this fact works, i only edit again my .pri file and erase the -m32 options, and the project is compiled